# Can Water Oxidize Cu(I) to Cu(II)

Tags: physical-chemistry, redox, water, oxidation-state

Is DI water (also without $\ce{O2}$ gas dissolved in it after degasification) a sufficiently strong oxidizer to oxidize $\ce{Cu(I)}$ in $\ce{Cu2O}$ to $\ce{Cu(II)}$ forming $\ce{CuO}$?

Will this change at elevated temperatures (e.g., 200 °C)?

Comment: Why do you even ask this?

Comment: @Mithoron I'm wondering whether it is possible to obtain pure Cu2O films via vacuum deposition techniques that uses water vapor as the co-reactant, or wll it require post-deposition treatments to remove the Cu(II).

Comment: Then I guess you should add a lot of details to question. If you simply put Cu2O to water then almost nothing happens, but with superheated vapor, I dunno...

Comment: Might there be the opposite problem?  Water vapor oxidizes copper metal to +1 only with difficulty if at all.  There is an old heat treating test for air vs moisture leaks based on the fact that copper is inert to water vapor.  http://www.airproducts.com/industries/Metals/ask-the-experts-metals/heat-treating/oxidation-cooling-section-continuous-furnace.aspx